# how to replace string from array before insert into table (codeigniter)?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have problem while insert data to database. 
I get error like this

```
Unknown column 'p.id_sp' in 'field list'
```

How to replace column name in sql query from

```
`p`.`id_sp'`
```

to `'p.id_sp'`. before running insert function ?

Here array example

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_pd] => 44b420b2-6f59-45e3-aa19-d2afa015ce95
                    [p.id_sp] => 
                    [p.telepon_rumah] => 
                    [p.telepon_seluler] => 
                    [email] => 
                )

        )

)
```

here my insert into code

```
    foreach($data["result"] as $key){
    $insert=$this->db->insert($database, $key);
}
this $insert produce query like this (INSERT INTO `STMIKTC_f055cfb2eefb3b4d4056efaafde7c679_tempmhs` (`id_pd`, `nm_pd`, `jk`, `nisn`, `nik`, `tmpt_lahir`, `tgl_lahir`, `id_agama`, `fk__agama`, `id_kk`, `fk__kk`, `p`.`id_sp`, `fk__sp`, `jln`, `rt`, `rw`, `nm_dsn`, `ds_kel`, `id_wil`, `fk__wil`, `kode_pos`, `id_jns_tinggal`, `fk__jns_tinggal`, `id_alat_transport`, `fk__alat_transport`, `p`.`telepon_rumah`, `p`.`telepon_seluler`, `email`, `a_terima_kps`, `no_kps`, `stat_pd`, `nm_ayah`, `tgl_lahir_ayah`, `id_jenjang_pendidikan_ayah`, `fk__jenjang_pendidikan_ayah`, `id_pekerjaan_ayah`, `fk__pekerjaan_ayah`, `id_penghasilan_ayah`, `fk__penghasilan_ayah`, `id_kebutuhan_khusus_ayah`, `fk__kebutuhan_khusus_ayah`, `nm_ibu_kandung`, `tgl_lahir_ibu`, `id_jenjang_pendidikan_ibu`, `fk__jenjang_pendidikan_ibu`, `id_pekerjaan_ibu`, `fk__pekerjaan_ibu`, `id_penghasilan_ibu`, `fk__penghasilan_ibu`, `id_kebutuhan_khusus_ibu`, `fk__kebutuhan_khusus_ibu`, `nm_wali`, `tgl_lahir_wali`, `id_jenjang_pendidikan_wali`, `fk__jenjang_pendidikan_wali`, `id_pekerjaan_wali`, `fk__pekerjaan_wali`, `id_penghasilan_wali`, `fk__penghasilan_wali`, `kewarganegaraan`) VALUES ('cb5ab906-a9b5-49f2-95e9-0d30ce005bd9', 'AULIYAH LINDA', 'P', NULL, NULL, 'JAYAPURA', '1987-01-23', '1', 'Islam', '0', 'Tidak ada', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Sekejati', '020000 ', 'Prop. Jawa Barat ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, '0', NULL, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', 'Tidak ada', 'ibu', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', 'Tidak ada', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'ID'))
```

Comment: there is no column with name `id_sp` associated with P alias

Comment: What is your column name `id_sp` or `p.id_sp`?

Comment: my collumn name is p.id_sp , but the query is `p`.`id_sp'` , so I should change `p`.`id_sp'` to p.id_sp, but I don't know how ?

Comment: you should pass it like 'p.id_sp' in query

Comment: why do you use a `.` (dot) in a column name? That collides with SQL-Syntax and makes everything hard to read and write. If there is no pressing reason, simply don't do it -- if you need the prefix, use `p_` instead of `p.`

Comment: @TomRegner I don't know, the data from server come with array like that ..

Answer (score 0):

Removing `'` from column name, I don't know it is possible or not.
But what you can do, is create alias of those columns which are problematic get into some temp table. then run your array and insert command.

Answer (score 0):

CI adds Backticks and stuff like that to the query in order to make this query safe, in your case however it looks like it's not possible to let CI do all the work because you use column names with dots

Try to change your code as follows:

```
foreach($data["result"] as $key){
    $insert=$this->db->insert($database, $key, false);
}
```

But keep in mind, you have to escape your data manually now

For more information take a look at the [query builder docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#CI_DB_query_builder::insert) and to the [driver reference docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=escape#CI_DB_driver::escape).

Comment: did you read the 2 lines below the code ?
you've to escape your data manually now